# Absolute positioned div same height as relative children

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a gradient as background on the body. The .main div is absolutely positioned. I want it to have the same height as the content inside it, but how can I achieve that?

Comment: Share your code to help you

Comment: You never want to have absolutely positioned elements as parents to relatively positioned children. You want it the other way around.  Most likely, that is the source of your problem.  Please read the article I posted in my answer for more about this.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do not have your main/container/wrapper div be absolutely positioned.  Have it be **positioned relatively**.

```
 <div class = "main">

    <div class = "content">....</div>

 </div>
```

Then you have your CSS:

```
.main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Look at this jFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/3eJGr/

A great article on what absolute positioning really does can be found [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/37-css-absolute-and-fixed-positioning/)

A segment:

> Absolutely positioned elements are removed entirely from the document
>   flow. That means they have no effect at all on their parent element or
>   on the elements that occur after them in the source code. An
>   absolutely positioned element will therefore overlap other content
>   unless you take action to prevent it.

Comment: You can see that the main div has a background of blue, but you cannot see it because the content div fills the entire area.

Comment: I need it to be positioned absolutely, because I want to center it, and I want to have an image centered in between the border of the main wrapper, and the side of the screen. Therefore, it needs to be positioned absolutely.

Comment: I think there is a better way.  However, it is hard to prove it to you without the code.  Can you make a jfiddle of your situation?

Comment: This is what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/aWUBk/ The blue div needs to be in the center of the whitespace that is on the right, so therefore it is positioned absolutely.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/aWUBk/1/  This is a much better way to do that without using absolute positions and random "hard coding." This example has a container width of 600px and the purple container is placed with a 25% or 150px margin.  The blue div is placed 25px after that since 150+ 300 = 450.  600-450 = 150.  150-100 = 50.  50 / 2 = 25.  Now, this can be easily scaled for your needs, for example, with a different container width, or with percentage widths.  Also, without a single absolutely positioned element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/aWUBk/2/  Here is an example of this converted into a layout based on percents, and yet, everything is still the same.  I hope this helps you my friend.  We have all been there with the absolute positioning, believe me! But it is definitely always better to not use it if you can find a way.  If this helped you, please give me a nice green check mark!  =)

Comment: How's it going? Any other questions?

Answer (score 1):

if the elements inside your absolute positioned div are positioned relative and have width and height you can apply this css to your `.main` div:

```
height:auto;
```

this will calculate the height depending on the height of all the content inside